# For the Taylor expansion of $(1+x)^n$ to be convergent, why must $-1 < x \leq 1$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

I understand that using the ratio test indicates that the series is convergent for $-1 < x < 1$ and divergent for $x<-1$ and $x>1$ but gives no indication of the validity of $x=1$ or $-1$. But my notes tell me to exclude $-1$ and include $1$ as the possible values of $x$.

For the Taylor expansion of $(1+x)^n$ to be convergent, why is the $x=-1$ excluded but $x=1$ included?

Is my explanation of why $x=1$ below right? If not, how should the reasoning go? If yes, is there a better argument?

My reasoning is as follows:
$x=1$ works because after a finite number of (or zero - when $n<0$) terms, signs will alternate between positive and negative (because of the new negative factor in numerator with each term) and the magnitude of terms decreases to zero in the limit of n approaching infinity (denominator>numerator for all alpha such that terms in the series oscillate). According to Leibniz criterion, the later part of the series is convergent and since there are a finite number of (or zero) terms in the earlier part of the series, the whole series is convergent.

For $x=-1$, I am not too sure of the explanation. I have only got as far as follows:
A similar reasoning as that of $x-1$ is used, except that the earlier part of the series has a finite number of (or zero) oscillating terms while the later part has all positive or all negative terms which are decreasing in magnitude. From here, I am not sure how to test if terms of the same sign with decreasing magnitude will cause the series to converge.

P.S. would appreciate if responses are kept to the Year 1 undergraduate level (I am not an undergraduate yet)

Comment: do you mean -2 <= x <= 0?

Comment: The Taylor series converges for *every* $x$. Where did you get that it converges only if $-1<x\leqslant1$?

Comment: The strict inequalities are found on the A-Level formula list under binomial expansion on the first page https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnwyMDE0c21jc3xneDo1ZDFmMTRhMTZlMjY3YjZh

For the expansion of (1+x)^n , doesn't it only converge for -1<x⩽1? If x has magnitude larger than 1, wouldn't each term get larger, causing the series to diverge?

Comment: @RyanTan What are you assuming about $n$?

Comment: n is any real number

Comment: @RyanTan Since you chose the letter $n$, I thought that it was a non-negative integer.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+x)^\alpha=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\binom{\alpha}{n}x^n$$ for $|x|<1$. Since $$\binom{\alpha}{n}=-\binom{\alpha}{n-1}\left(1-\frac{\alpha+1}{n}\right),$$ the absolute value of $\binom{\alpha}{n}$ is $O(n^{-\alpha-1})$.
This means: if $\alpha>0,$ the series is convergent for $x=-1$ and $x=1$, for $-1<\alpha<0,$ the series converges for $x=1$ (alternating series with eventually monotone decreasing terms) and diverges for $x=-1$. For $\alpha\le-1,$ the series diverges for both values of $x$.
The simplest example for the latter case is $$\frac1{1+x}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}(-1)^nx^n,$$
quite obviously diverging for $x=1.$